# Which plant can co-exist with the other plant?

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, plant-recommendations, fruits, companion-planting

I have picked up the following list of plants and have only 4 decent size pots. Which plants can be grown together in the same pot?

- pepper
- tomato super fantastic
- tomato sweet 100
- basil
- oregano thumb
- kent strawberry
- cucumber pickling
- pepper early red
- pepper jalapeno
- onion green bunching
- rosemary
- lettuce

Comment: What do you mean by „decent size pots“?

Comment: Most or all the plants you mention need their own pots - but it does depend on the precise size/measurements of the pots you have.  For example, if one of the  containers is a trough 8inches deep by 3 feet long, you might bet the pepper plants in it, or the lettuce and basil. You growing these indoors or out? (houseplant tag?)

Answer (score 1):

Gardening, like a lot of things in life, is about **balance**: finding the best outcome for a given circumstance with several pros and cons.

- Occasionally in gardening there are beneficial combinations such as peas, squash, and corn that can be grown right next to each other in a harmonious way in certain environments.
- Most of the plants on your list should ideally be grown in their own space. A large pot (about 10 gallons?) is only enough space to grow 1 of those items. It can be hard to find space to give each plant as much as it /ideally/ wants to maximize production.
- In a large pot you could combine 1 small, low-height item with shallow roots (lettuce, rosemary, oregano, onion, strawberry, and basil) with 1 taller item with deeper roots (peppers, tomatoes). You need to be careful that the shorter item is in front of the taller item so they aren't competing for sun. For example: you could try growing some lettuce in the same pot as a single jalapeño as long as they are oriented and planted in a timing that gives them both light. You will probably get slightly smaller production from both plants, but it will be tolerable.
- Attempting to combine multiple tomatoes or a tomato and a pepper in a single pot will reduce the production of each plant. However, if you have very limited space and your goal is a variety of produce rather than maximizing the per-plant production.

A neighbor of mine grew 4 tomatoes in a single whiskey barrel last summer. She put chicken-wire around them to hold them together and protect them from squirrels. It certainly reduced the production of each plant, but it meant she had 4 different kinds of tomatoes in a very small amount of space. That was a balance she was willing to make.

Answer (score 1):

Pots and soil limit growth for large plants such as tomatoes, kale and broccoli unless you go with barrels. However you CAN use Kratky to grow such plants in a single 3.5 gallon bucket. Kratky is a passive, simple hydroponic method that does not use soil. I regularly combine multiple plants in a single Kratky 3.5gallon bucket. When combining plants in a Kratky bucket, you would need to consider how the foliage interact since nutrition is less important because of availability. For example, snow peas and tomatoes can go in the same bucket.

With pots and soil, your options will be more limited. My potted plants never do as well as their clones in raised bed or hyrdoponics. I only combine herbs in pots.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the above answers (which may not be what you wanted to hear). Rosemary and oregano are perennials (rosemary is evergreen, oregano is not). You don't want to plant a rosemary which will live for many years on top of e.g. a tomato which will live for one year, exhaust the soil in your pot, and then need to be removed and discarded and presumably new soil added before planting another tomato next year. I've grown up to 4 tomato plants in the same planter (cylindrical, about 18" diameter by 18" high) with good results, and imagine you could get decent results either planting lettuce or basil beneath them, and/or swapping out a tomato for a cucumber, which also grow on vines and can be trained into a column or allowed to trail over the side of the pot. Strawberry pots traditionally are tall have many holes down the sides, so if your pots are a suitable material you could try punching holes in the sides and plugging these with your strawberry plants

Answer (score 0):

If you have four pots I would dedicate one of them for the herbs you listed, like the rosemary, oregano and basil. As for the other three pots I would dedicate two in a combination of pepper/lettuce or tomato/lettuce and for the last one I would put the strawberries in. You would have a mixed and decent harvest and well the cucumber and the onions need their own special spaces for when you have the availability for them.